# How to play computer from a particular position on chess.com app

Tags: computer-chess, chess.com

I started playing chess a month ago and sometimes I would like to play a hard computer from a particular position (e.g., practicing not blundering in openings, or practice winning a won endgame position). However, it doesn't seem like there is a way on the Chess.com app to load a PGN and play against a particular bot. Obviously if I start a game against a 3200 bot then I won't be able to reach the part of the game I want to practice in.

Is there a way to do what I describe in Chess.com or perhaps another website/app?

Comment: Schmidt, there is a better answer that does not require switching websites. Check it out.

Comment: @fartgeek I did see that one, however I use the Chess.com mobile app, so both answers require me to go to a website.

Comment: And I think I like Lichess better now that I found out about it.

Comment: mmmmmm yes the lichess website is objectively better than the chess.com app, but the chess.com website is better than lichess (having played on all three for significant periods of time, I can say that...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this via Lichess:

1. Visit [lichess](https://lichess.org) and optionally create an account if you haven't done so.
2. Click Play with the computer.
3. Select "From Position" in the Variant field.
4. Insert the position FEN you want to play with the computer.
5. Choose a time control.
6. Choose the computer level. See [this](https://lichess.org/forum/general-chess-discussion/stockfish-rating-levels-underrated) discussion for more info on what those mean.
7. Select a colour (White, Black or random).

Good luck!

Comment: Lichess is really cool, I figured out I can also enable Stockfish in the analysis board right in the browser. Thanks!

Comment: @TankorSmash I don't think they are either, but in my question I said "or perhaps another website/app".

Answer (score 17):

You can also do this on chess.com.

1. Go to the "Learn" Tab
2. Click on "Analysis"
3. Setup your position via FEN or just by placing pieces
4. Click "Finish vs Computer"

Comment: This is a nice answer. If you add a comment and give analysis, it will probably beat the other one later. I am upvoting now, in hope of improvement.

Comment: Nice! Since I use the mobile app either Chess.com or Lichess.org both require me to go to a website but thank you for showing me how to do this on Chess.com!

Comment: @BitChaser Tried my best to improve it. Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this in the chess.com app (or at least you could in a previous version.)

Tap the "Computer" menu button.

When it shows the starting options, tap "Position". (This is the bottom option; you may need to scroll down to see it.)

It gives you a list of choices. Tap "Custom Setup".

You can now set up the position as you like. Drag pieces around, add new ones from the bottom, or tap one to get rid of it. You can reset or clear the board from the menu icon. Tap the checkmark to finish setting up the position.

Set whatever other options you like, and start the game.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see "Position" as an option after selecting "Custom". Perhaps it's because I'm on Android and you're on an iPhone?

Comment: You mean after selecting "Computer"? It's right below "Show Blunders". Like I said, you may have to scroll to see it.

Comment: Hmm, mine seems different, first, it's "Play Computer" on the main menu, but there is no "Show Blunders" option. Let me try to link to a couple screenshots.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/65AIVsR

Comment: That's certainly different from what I'm seeing. My version is v3.8.6-19706.

Comment: I'm on v4.2.3-googleplay-210358. I'm surprised they removed this feature lol.