Chess.com: Is there a way to save a game in the middle?
When playing against the computer at chess.com, is there a way to save a game in the middle and then return to it after I'm checkmated to try again with a different strategy?

https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/33444/34536 May answer your question.

@Awalrod That method requires setting up the board in the intermediate position. I wanna save the game and then restore it to that state, like any other computer game.


"Copy PGN" is in the options available to you during a computer game. Copy the PGN of the position you would like to save and paste it into a note or text it to yourself.
Under the Learn/Analysis feature should be an option to paste PGN. Paste your pgn into analysis
Select "Finish against computer" and play your saved game

